# Sender Policy Framework Qualifiers

Tags: spf

RFC4408 defines the Sender Policy Framework (SPF).

SPF has qualifiers ("-", "~", "+", "?") which are defined as (fail,softfail,pass,neutral) respectively.

There is confusion amongst information online regarding the use of - versus ~. I need some assistance from an expert.

My assumption is that Google uses ~all instead of -all because their _spf.google.com resolves to a _netblocks host which is a dynamic record (according to Google's website since they use the word 'current' when describing the _netblocks) and, therefore, because of DNS propogation delay the ~ was used as opposed to -.

However, when I look stuff up on SendGrid support, I get examples using - and ~ for the same scenario (same hosts and so forth). The only difference is - and ~.

My guess is most e-mail clients are properly configured such that ~ softfail pass throughs result in a flagged message indicating that the sender may not be legit. Is this a safe assumption? It seems like the big smtp companies made that assumption.

https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-u...cles/202517236 <-- says use -

https://sendgrid.com/docs/Glossary/spf.html <-- says use ~

Thanks in advance friends.

Comment: Can you state the question you are asking more clearly?

Comment: Basically, why did Google opt to use ~ instead of -?  I presume it has something to do with dynamic DNS and DNS propogation time so as to make sure e-mails do in fact get through.  However, I wanted a definitive answer.  Thank you so much in advance!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Softfail (~all) should indeed be treated as an indication that the Domain Owner believes the host is not authorized, but is unwilling to make a strong policy statement. This encourages email processors to subject the message to further scrutiny before accepting the message.

The problems with using -all are:

- Broken DMARC architectures may fail messages at -all instead of completing DMARC evaluation, thus violating DMARC spec and causing delivery issues.
- DNS propagation delays are far more likely to affect large SMTP operators when they make IP changes since mail receivers are far more likely to have received email from those DNS records in the last few minutes.

  - Google uses a TTL of 5 minutes but given more than 5 million businesses use Google Apps, Google is delivering email for itself and its customers regularly enough to some servers that DNS delays could be a concern.
- For domains using DMARC, using -all will cause a noticeable difference in how email is processed by non DMARC compliant third parties. DMARC compliant third parties may still accept a message if DKIM passes and is aligned with DMARC domain. However non DMARC compliant third parties wouldn't run DMARC/DKIM checks at all and simply reject at SPF check time if using -all. Organizations may be more willing to trust a strong DMARC assertion to be used against their domain since it covers EHLO, DKIM and From: domain, and thus more thorough.

For the reasons above an organization may not be as willing to trust an SPF only assertion to be used against them and their mail flows.

For their part Google recommends to their customers [to deploy DMARC](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2466580) to cut down on domain spoofing and recommends [using ~all in SPF to prevent delivery issues](https://support.google.com/a/answer/178723).